# The name 'EntityState' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, runtime-error

In *Entity Framework*, this sometimes occurs when the `System.data.entity` assembly is not added into the Project. But, why I didn't have this error before in other MVC project.

it occurs sometimes but frequently and I have to add it manually in *Add References*. What can I do?

Comment: Did you check the version of your entity framework? Take a look in here too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17843055/1384539

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed this issue as below

**Namespace**

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
```

I was working earlier in ASP.Net MVC C# application working fine for me.
I fixed this issue as below

```
using System.Data;
```

I was working earlier in ASP.Net MVC C# application working fine for me

```
_context.Entry(_Teach).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

Now, same method using in simple c#, WCF but it giving me issue then I did this in a way as below:

```
_context.Entry(_Teach).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 22):

Try changing

e.g.

```
System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

to

```
System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

(Not sure what's going on. Did Microsoft change the package?)

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this problem by including the namespace it's from:

**using System.Data.Entity;**

Answer (score 2):

When I had this problem, I fixed it by including the namespace it's from:

```
using System.Data;
```

More info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved for me when I added

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Maybe that will work?

Answer (score 0):

You should make changes as below in code.

```
 public ActionResult Edit(Album album)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(album).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artist, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
        return View(album);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you have added reference to `System.Data.Entity`

**Right click on "References" under your project library > Add Reference...**

[image: Make sure you have added reference to System.Data.Entity]